# Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

`TodoManager.getInstance()` is a new `TodoManager` object and every row is different,I have my own adapter.I used  int position(the element for the row )in everywhere.I need to `changesetStatus()` method of my base class.How to I get int position here?
pos is the ith spinner item,this can't be as position

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            TodoManager.getInstance().getTodo(pos).setStatus(selectedItem);
//  more code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try associating with your items in the spinner an indexing tag. You should do it before inflating the spinner. You can associate a tag with  `View` method: `setTag(int key, Object tag)` method for potential spinner list item. Then in the `onItemSelected` method you can retrieve the right object with `View.findViewWithTag()`.